# chat app using websocket python+django+angular

Tags: python, django, angular, websocket

I want to make one real-time chat application using websockets and the frontend is angular5.

So, I create websocket in purepython and backend is Django and frontend is angular5.

Myquestion is when i create websocket service in python. So, do i have to make websockets services in angular too?

this is my python websocket service

```
async def consumer_handler(websocket):
    global glob_message
    while True:
        message = await websocket.recv()
        await glob_message.put(message)
        print("this went in glob_message: {}".format(message))

async def producer_handler(websocket):
    global glob_message
    while True:
        message = await glob_message.get()
        await websocket.send(message)

async def handler(websocket, path):
    producer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(producer_handler(websocket))
    consumer_task = asyncio.ensure_future(consumer_handler(websocket))
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(
        [consumer_task, producer_task],
        return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,
    )

    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    glob_message = asyncio.Queue()
    start_server = websockets.serve(
            handler,
            '127.0.0.1', 8788)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

So, i want to create two user can send and receive messages.so must be design in angular ..

so i am asking that i already create one service in python so do i have to create websocket service(Observable subscribers) in angular too?

Comment: is this question still open ?

Comment: no @madjaoue it is close...

Answer (score 2):

In your angular side, you should open a connection indeed.

This is how you can use Observables to communicate with your server :

**Client side**

```
// open the socket connection
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8788')

// when opened, print all messages
ws.onopen = open => { 
      Observable.fromEvent(ws, 'message')
        .subscribe(message => console.log(message)) 
      }
```

To send a message, simply use :

```
ws.send('test')
```

**Server Side**

You can use the demo in https://pypi.org/project/websocket-client/ to build your websocket server.

to import WebSocket :

`pip install websocket-client`

Then :

```
import websocket
try:
    import thread
except ImportError:
    import _thread as thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    def run(*args):
        for i in range(3):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
        ws.close()
        print("thread terminating...")
    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://127.0.0.1:8788",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Comment: okay... Thnks..If you i have some tutorial link .. please suggest me.. so i can refer..

Comment: With this, you should be able to send and receive messages between angular and python. Your next step is to redirect these messages to the right person.
This is not a tutorial, but a solved similar problem. Maybe it can help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356426/chatbot-using-websockets-in-angular-4-and-django

Comment: I updated my comment with code for a WebSocket server in python. Hope this helps.